# How to properly serve private static files with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to protect images which are uploaded. When users upload images, they are saved to the following path:

```
public/dogs/{userId}/{imageName}
```

Each user has it's own directory where images are saved. I've figured out I can easily serve those images if I do something like this but the images are then accessible by everybody:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

My user validation works in the way that I check does the request url contains `/api/admin` in the path. Example:

```
router.get('/api/admin/dogs', dog.getAll);
```

I would like to serve the images in the similar way to just allow admin to access them. Is it possible to have something like this:

```
router.get('/api/admin/dogs/images/:userId/:imageName', image.getOne);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `sendFile` function available on `response` object. You can use it to send the file based on you user validation.

It would be something like this:

```
router.get('/api/admin/dogs/images/:userId/:imageName', function(req, res, next){
  currentUserHasAccessTo(userId, imageName, function(err) {
    if (err)
      next(err)
    else
      res.sendFile(`public/dogs/${userId}/${imageName}`)
  })
});
```

`currentUserHasAccessTo` is your validation function that would  query a database  or something else.
If an error is returned, it will be passed to the error handler middleware so  that it can show a default image or an error page.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use stacking of handlers:

```
router.get('/api/admin/dogs/images/:userId/:imageName', function(req, res, next){
  currentUserHasAccessTo(userId, imageName, function(err) {
   if (err)
     next(err); // or res.send(401) if unauthorized
   else
     res.next() ; // this will "jump" to the express.static below
  })
, express.static('public') });
```

In this case, you have two handlers for a single route. The second one will be reached only if next() is called...